# changing Oscillator type in Web Audio API with a range slider

Tags: html5-audio, web-audio-api

i managed to make the slider to change to oscillator frequency but does not work for the oscillator type.

here is the jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/aKDkf/1/

and Here is the JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var context = new webkitAudioContext();
var osc = context.createOscillator();

//initializing oscillator type to 0 (Sinewave)
osc.type=0;
$('oscType').change(function(){
osc.type = $(this).val();
})

//setting initial OSC frequency to 440.
osc.frequency.value = 440;
//changing  Oscillator's frequency with the range input
$('#oscFreq').change(function(){
osc.frequency.value = $(this).val()
})



$('#onOff').click(function () {
    this.value = this.value === 'ON' ? 'OFF' : 'ON';
});


$('#onOff').click(function () {
    var buttonValue = $('#onOff').val();

    // creating AudioContext


    if (buttonValue === 'OFF') {
        osc.connect(context.destination);
        osc.noteOn(0);

    } else if (buttonValue === 'ON') {
        osc.disconnect(0);
    }


});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

First, on line 7, your selector is wrong. Needs to be `$('#oscType')`. Yours was missing the `#`.

Secondly, on line 8, you need to change to `osc.type = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);`, because input values are always strings and you need an integer.

Comment: yeah thanks i fixed it, silly mistake. now its working. what exactly the second argument in the parseInt does? i mean 10.

Comment: The second argument is called the radix, or base. It's always a good idea to supply one - because you can run into weird issues in certain cases. For example, some browsers will interpret the string `"065"` as `53`, because they assume that the leading zero means it's an octal, or base-8.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check for other possible issues, but according to the web audio API specs you should pass in a string indicating the desired type instead of a int, see the [deprecation notes](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#DeprecationNotes)

```
//OscillatorNode constants for the .type attribute

//New way  
enum OscillatorType {"sine",
                     "square",   
                     "sawtooth", 
                     "triangle",
                     "custom" }
```

Comment: its working when i change it manually to 1 , and changes the oscillator type to square wave, but does not work with the slider.

Comment: @EhsanZiya, does the jQuery on your slider give you ints or strings?

Comment: i dont really know, how can i test?

Comment: now i did it with a radio selector and its working http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/b39Dq/1/

Comment: @EhsanZiya, fine. you can test with `typeof(<your var>)` and cast to number with `Number(<your var>)`

Comment: i tried for both of the sliders/ both are undefined. that is the reason its not working. but i wonder why it works for the oscillator node.